# JScrollBar does not stretch properly in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout, stretch, jscrollbar

All I want is a Label and a JScrollBar beneath. The scrollbar shouldn't even have any function. I also want the slider to be a little wider than the label. 
For example: if the label is 10 pixels wide, then the JscrollBar should be 20 pixels wide. Both should centered.
I know, that working with preferredSizes or fixed sizes at all is not good. So I want to avoid that and try it with a GridBagLayout.

Unluckily my scollbar is not able to stretch properly. Here is my code so far.

```
package kapitel13;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
public class übung7 extends JFrame {
  public übung7(String titel) {
    super(titel);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Lautstärke"); // means volume
    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    gbc.gridwidth=3;
    //gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    add(label, gbc);

    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    gbc.gridwidth=23;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    add(scrollBar, gbc);

    /*
    JButton btn = new JButton("Button1");
    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.gridy=3;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.gridwidth=3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    add(btn, gbc);
    */
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    übung7 win = new übung7("Win");
    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);
    win.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you make the **gridWidth** larger for the scrollbar it does not get bigger than the label, because there are no items left or right of the label. All the cells get squashed to zero pixels. If you put some empty labels in it should work :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("                            "); 
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
add(label, gbc);


JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Lautstärke"); // means volume
gbc.gridx=2;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
add(label2, gbc);


JLabel label3 = new JLabel("                             "); 
gbc.gridx=3;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
add(label3, gbc);


JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=2;
gbc.gridwidth=3;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
add(scrollBar, gbc);
```

Alternatively you could play around with the **weights**. This should stretch out the scrollbar too :

```
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Lautstärke"); // means volume
gbc.gridx=2;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.weightx=1;
add(label2, gbc);

JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=2;
gbc.gridwidth=3;
gbc.weightx=1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
add(scrollBar, gbc);
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I found when looking into the problem. Also, for a little more description I found an example/tutorial from Oracle describing this functionality
  [OracleExample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: I describe a bit more about 'weights' in my GridBag tutorial : http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/

Comment: Works pretty good :) Thanks so far. If you can also help me to center the JScrollbar, then I mark your answer as the accepted answer. Because right now the label and the scrollbar are both aligned both on the left side. But the scrollbar should stick out on the left and on the right side of my label a bit.

Comment: Checked out a few tutorials even before I asked the question by the way. Also the 2 links that you two suggested. I couldn't find there a part, that tells me the neat trick to just insert empty labels or how to center cells :/

Comment: are you sure it doesnt work for you? I put a screenshot of what I see. The top code example with the gridWidth is what I mean.